# FileNotFoundError: When pushing excel files to sftp server

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-not-found

I have been trying to push excel file to sftp server through python from windows local system.

Below is the code which i have tried.

```
import pandas as pd
import paramiko
sftpURL   =  '100.35.1.16'
sftpUser  =  'xyz'
sftpPass  =  'user@123'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(sftpURL, username=sftpUser, password=sftpPass,port=6381)
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
localPath = "D:/folder/myfolder/abc.xlsx"
sftpPath = "/home/var/reports/abc.xlsx"
files = ftp.put(sftpPath,localPath)
```

Post executing this I am seeing this error listed below

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/home/var/reports/abc.xlsx'
```

I am able to connect to the sftp server through Filezilla, also when I list the directories through Python code it is successful, but when pushing file to the same location through Python I am getting this issue.

I have tried most of the research online too & also used the package pysftp too, but no luck.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the [`put()` method](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put) is:

```
put(localpath, remotepath, callback=None, confirm=True)
```

It appears you've reversed your arguments. Change your put call to:

```
files = ftp.put(localPath, sftpPath)
```

Comment: Hi glibdud, 
i have tried your suggestion & this is the error i am getting:

OSError: File not open for writing,

Comment: That is a different problem. I'd recommend asking a new question and including the full traceback of that error.

Comment: thanks, that worked.... i have used the complete file location in ftp.put rather than passing it as a variable....